# visualization of two sets of confidence intervals in a scatterplot

Tags: data-visualization

I am seeking some general ideas on how to more effectively present two sets of confidence intervals in a scatterplot. There are a total of 10 point estimates and the associated 20 CIs, 10 on each dimension. The difficulty is that, some confidence interval is very wide, so if I draw them vertically and horizontally for each point, then the plot would be very ugly... Is there a more effective way to incorporate both CIs for each point in a scatterplot? It may not be limited to drawing lines, other solutions using different visualization methods are also good. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the "ugly" version of your visualization so that we can see the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the data, I would suggest to use log scale for the dimension with wide intervals. If this simple trick does not solve the problem, please add your current visualization to your question.